# How to link using GCC commands in Bloodshed Dev-C++

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, dev-c++

I was trying to figure out how to link Fortran and C++ code, and one of the tutorials had written 2 programs, one in C++ in a file named `testC.cpp`, and the other in Fortran in a file named `testF.f` but I need to input the following compilation instructions:

```
gfortran -c testF.f
g++ -c testC.cpp
g++ -o test testF.o testC.o -lg2c
```

Problem is, I'm working in an IDE called Bloodshed Dev-C++ so I have no idea how to do this. I tried going in compiler options and in the general section I appended those instructions in the option "add the following commands when calling the compiler". Doesn't work.

Comment: What is *"Doesn't work!"*? That is not a problem statement. What actually happens? Any message? How did you come up with `-lg2c`? It should be `-lgfortran`.

Comment: Pro tip: don't use Bloodshed Dev-C++ (in what Stone Age cave did you find this relic?). It is old, which means it is very old, so old it actually isn't really relevant anymore and will cause a lot of headaches that will ruin the fun of learning.

Comment: @rubenvb what IDE do you suggest on windows? One in which it's easy to link to gcc like I posted?

Comment: Qt Creator, Eclipse, Code::Blocks. You can get MinGW-w64 (i.e. GCC for Windows) from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe).

Comment: Of course I meant `g++ -o test testF.o testC.o -lgfortran`. I thought it is obvious. And again "doesn't work" **doesn't mean anything**.

Comment: @VladimirF sorry. Tried that now. Works like a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you need use custom Makefile. Project->project options. Or include *.mak files